# sending an email in angular 14

Tags: angular, typescript, gmail

I want to send an automatic email in a certain case,
That is, if the status is above 79, I want it to send a warning email before blocking the system
I tried several things but none of them helped me.
for example:

Email.send({
SecureToken : "C973D7AD-F097-4B95-91F4-40ABC5567812",
To : 'them@website.com',
From : "you@isp.com",
Subject : "This is the subject",
Body : "And this is the body"
}).then(
message => alert(message)
)

i tried also this :

```
const mailOptions = {
     from: 'YourMail@gmail.com',
     to: 'YourFreindMail@gmail.com',
     subject: 'SUBJECT',
     body: 'BODY',
     bcc: 'YourMail@gmail.com'
   };
  
   const transporter = Nodemailer.createTransport({
     service: 'gmail',
     auth: {
       user: 'YourMail@gmail.com',
       password: '******'
     }
   });
  
   transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, info) => {
     if (err) {
       console.error(err);
     } else {
       console.log(info);
     }
   });
 }
```

And nothing helped. Do you have another way to help me please?

Answer (score 2):

`Nodemailer` is a module meant to run in a Node.js backend, not from a Angular frontend.

Btw, you can't send email from a browser, you'll need to rely on a service provided by the backend !